# How to add a little triangle shape to the end of a component withy Styled Components?

Tags: react-native, styled-components

I am building an app in React Native and styling is definitely a weak point.

I need to achieve something like this:

[image]

To be more precise, the things I need a pointer in the right direction for (excuse the pun) is:

1. how to draw a triangle
2. the correct use of absolute position and Z-index to position it (assuming that's what I should be using).

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust your position based on your layout.

```js
const Triangle = styled(View)`
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-top-width: 10px;
  border-bottom-width: 10px;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-left-width: 14px;
  border-left-color: red;
`;
```